# Programmatically add table of contents when importing acticles into confluence

Tags: confluence

I want to migrate existing articles from another system to confluence and my current approach is to use the document import feature to import their html print version, which works very well so far.

Now these articles have static tables of contents (TOC) which I want to replace with the dynamic confluence TOC macro.

I've tried the different macro options described here https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf59/table-of-contents-macro-792499210.html but none of them works and just shows the macro in plain text after the html file is imported into confluence.

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc">...</ac:structured-macro>
```

and

```
{toc:printable=true|...}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by placing a placeholder `#TOC#` in the page and replacing it afterwards via a SQL statement on the database.

```
UPDATE bodycontent SET body = REPLACE(body, '#TOC#', '<ac:structured-macro ac:name="toc" />')
```

You have to flush the page cache afterwards.